# Why does gradle init generate variable mainClass, while mainClassName is needed?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jar

When I run `gradle init` with Gradle 6.7.1, a `gradle.build` file is built that has a `mainClass` variable. Yet this needs to be `mainClassName` and if `mainClass` is used, it fails. See details below.

Why does `gradle init` generate unusable code?

Relevant portion of `gradle.build`:

```
application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.MyFileKt'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Error message if we replace both occurrences of `mainClassName` with `mainClass`.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/joshua/dev/multicloud/app/build.gradle' line: 47

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'mainClass' for object of type org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "generates unusable code"? Was the `jar { ... }` part generated by the gradle init? It looks to me like copy-pasted from a legacy script. The `mainClassName` property of the `application` object is deprecated and the `mainClass` should be used instead. The difference is that it cannot be accessed as a root-level property anymore.

The following should work:

```
application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'com.mycompany.MyFileKt'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `configurations.compile` part is still wrong though (it should be using `runtimeClasspath`).

Comment: @BjørnVester  You are right, `compile` has been deprecated as well, but as per 6.7.1 it still works.

Comment: Thank you. I added the error message, above.
 
I am using 6.7.1 but also tried 6.8.2.  

Thanks for the tip about `compile`. I will move to `implementation`

Using `application.` before `mainClass` does the trick